# ElasticSearch Filter and match using NEST query

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm currently working on implementing ES in .NET using NEST.

problem:
I have four docs in my ES index and I want to get the records which contain a word and date greater than today's date.

```
class P{
    public int id;
    public string text;
    public DateTime date;
}
```

for eg: these are the four records I have.(these are the values passed to ES)

1. id:1, text: this is post1, date= DateTime.Now;
2. id:1, text: this is another post, date= DateTime.Now;
3. id:2, text: This is post from ES, date= DateTime.Now;
4. id:3, text: this is post from ES FUTURE, date= DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

this is my version of code for the same:

```
var result =
                client.Search<P>(s => s
                .Query(p => p.Term(q => q.text, "ES"))
                .Query(b => b.Bool(a =>     a.Filter(t=>t.Range(r=>r.Field("date").GreaterThan(2016-08-04)))))  );
```

Now I want to write a query using Lamba query to find all the docs which contain the word ES and the date greater than today's date.(expected output should be 4)

Can someone help me in solving this?

Comment: May you share part of your code where do you create index and set up mapping?

Comment: And what version of elasticsearch and NEST are you using. That would be helpful as well ;)

Comment: #for indexing and mapping
`client.CreateIndex("my_blog");
             client.Map<P>(m => m.AutoMap());`

#for entering data
`var newBlogPost3 = new P
            {
                id = 2,
                date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
                text = " this is post from ES FUTURE"
            };`

#for entering data
            `client.Index(newBlogPost3);`

Comment: @ASN please edit your question to add additional information